# How get json array

Tags: php, json

I am using JSON in my php pages. I am formatting json data from my mysql datebase. But somehow json data is not formatted correctly.

I have

```
{"imei":"44fd02f38e4a5c0c","dolgota":"49.406","shirota":"53.5412","date":"2014\/05\/13 13:24:16"}{"imei":"a2422857b2cccf4c","dolgota":"49.4385","shirota":"53.5142","date":"2014\/05\/13 11:22:09"}
```

but what I want

```
[{"imei":"44fd02f38e4a5c0c","dolgota":"49.406","shirota":"53.5412","date":"2014\/05\/13 13:24:16"},{"imei":"a2422857b2cccf4c","dolgota":"49.4385","shirota":"53.5142","date":"2014\/05\/13 11:22:09"}]
```

this is my code

```
$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `kordinates`";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $json_data = array('imei'=>$row['imei'],'dolgota'=>$row['dolgota'],'shirota'=>$row['shirota'],'date'=>$row['date']);
    echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

First take all data in array and then use json_encode after your loop complete,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $json_data[] = array('imei'=>$row['imei'],'dolgota'=>$row['dolgota'],'shirota'=>$row['shirota'],'date'=>$row['date']);       
}
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

then just put your array in an array:

```
$json_data = 
array(array('imei'=>$row['imei'],'dolgota'=>$row['dolgota'],'shirota'=>$row['shirota'],'date'=>$row['date']));
```